# Launching a shell script file from a JavaScript web page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a website where I created a simple form in JS:
 [Launch form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpWae.png)

```
   function()
    {

var thePrompt = window.open("", "", "widht=50");
    var theHTML = "";

    theHTML += "<p>Please insert the IP,TestCaseID and your credentials</p>";
    theHTML += "<br/>";
    theHTML += "IPprinter: <input type='text' id='theIP' placeholder='Enter Printer IP'/>";
    theHTML += "<br/>";
    theHTML += "TestCaseID: <input type='text' id='theID' placeholder='Enter TestCase ID'/>";
    theHTML += "<br/>";
    theHTML += "Username: <input type='text' id='theUser' placeholder='Enter Username'/>";
    theHTML += "<br />";
    theHTML += "Password: <input type='text' id='thePass' placeholder='Enter Password'/>";
    theHTML += "<br />";
    theHTML += "<input type='button' value='Launch' id='Launch'/>";
    thePrompt.document.body.innerHTML = theHTML;

    var theIP = thePrompt.document.getElementById("theIP").value;
    var theID = thePrompt.document.getElementById("theID").value;
    var theUser = thePrompt.document.getElementById("theUser").value;
    var thePass = thePrompt.document.getElementById("thePass").value;
    thePrompt.document.getElementById("Launch").onclick = function () {
        var process = require('child_process');
process.exec('./var/www/html/mytest/TestAPI.sh',function (err,stdout,stderr) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("\n"+stderr);
    } else {
        console.log(stdout);
    }
});
    }
```

When I click the "Launch" button to launch the script from "/var/www/html/mytest/TestAPI.sh" nothing happens.
Where I am wrong or is there another way to execute that script, maybe using PHP?!

I know this appears to be a security hole with launching a script from a web page but this is done in a controlled environment after users are login. 
Any ideas are welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to call a PHP page that execute my script:
javascript:

```
location.href = "test.php";
```

php page(test.php):

```
<?php
   $outcome = shell_exec('/var/www/html/mytest.sh 2>&1');
   echo $outcome;
?>
```

However, to be able to run that script you must configure selinux on "permissive".
There are much secure method instead of lowering the web server security to "permissive" but does't work for my shell script( I call to many programs and other scripts).

Answer (score 0):

from what I know, process.exec() is a node.js code.. it does not run on the browser
there is a difference from Browser Javascript and Node.Js

Both may use the same language but the environment that they run is different.

so **if** the "/var/www/html/mytest/TestAPI.sh" file is on your server
therefor you can use PHP or even nodeJS to run it. you just need to create an endpoint that runs that script.

if you're going to use PHP then I think you can use [shell_exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to achieve this.